# C error : expected expression before int (when I call the function I get error that an expression is missing)

Tags: c

I am getting errors that some expression is missing

```
#include <stdio.h>
void pairmul(int* p,int n,int sum){
int arr[n];
int q;
for(int i =0; i<=n-1; i++){
    arr[i] = *(p+i);
}
for(int j = 0;j<=n-1;j++){
    for(int k=j+1;k<=n-1;k++){
        int temp;
        if(arr[j]>arr[k]){
            temp = arr[k];
            arr[k] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
if(arr[0]+ arr[1]<sum){
    q = arr[0]*arr[1];
    printf("%d",q);
}
else if(n<2){
    printf("-1");
}
else{
    printf("0");
}
return 0;

}

int main(){
     int sum,n;
     int array[n];
     printf("Sum and Size of array");
     scanf("%d %d \n",&sum,&n);
     for(int i =0; i<=n-1; i++){
         scanf("%d",&array[i]);
}
pairmul(&array[0], int n,int sum);
return 0;
}
```

pairmul(&array[0], int n,int sum);

I have error with this expression that there are very few arguments and
2nd is that there is some expression before 'int'

Comment: Why are you specifying the type when calling the function as well?

Comment: When declaring a function, you must specify the type of each parameter.  When calling the function, you must not specify the types. In other words, remove the `int`

Comment: `pairmul(&array[0], int n,int sum);` makes no sense. Nor does the undefined behavior of the VLA `array` you're declaring without an actual specified size (variable or otherwise). At `int array[n];` the variable `n` has no determinate value. That array doesn't magically resize later in the code just because you change the value of `n`. The decl has to come *after* you've set `n`.

Comment: What is the value of `n` before `int array[n];` -- issue? A `void` function does not `return 0;` and `pairmul (array, n, sum);` would be the proper call in `main()`. You cannot use ANY input function correctly unless you ***Check The Return*** to determine if the input succeeded or failed. (especially with `scanf()` where a *matching-failure* can occur) `i <= n - 1` should be `i < n`...

Comment: Get rid of `"%d %d \n"` it's just `"%d %d"`

Comment: Are you sure? Do your inputs look like `if (scanf ("%d %d", &sum, &n) != 2) { /* handle error */ }`? Where you handle the error either by exiting, or to recover, you must empty `stdin` of the characters causing the *matching-failure*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you recall the syntax of a function?

```
func(var1, var2, var3);
```

Right? But in your code `pairmul(&array[0], int n,int sum);`, you use this syntax:

```
func(var1, datatype var2, datatype var3);
```

That makes no sense. Change

```
pairmul(&array[0], int n,int sum);
```

into

```
pairmul(&array[0], n,sum);
```

And your code will work properly.

I think that the reason you are confused is because may have been confused by a function like macro. Eg.

```
#define MAKE_SQUARE_AND_STORE(datatype, var, num) datatype var = num * num 

int main() {
    MAKE_SQUARE_AND_STORE(int, square, 3);
    printf("%d\n", square);
}
```

This works because macros replace text, so this code is actually converted to:

```
int main() {
    int square = 3 * 3;
    printf("%d\n", square);   
}
```

And this code is fed into the actual compiler. Function like macros are a way different thing.

This is an even crazier macro:

```
#define DECLARE_SQUARE(dec, num) dec = num * num
```

And in this case, your weird syntax works.

```
DECLARE_SQUARE(int sqr, 3);
/*Preprocesses into:
int sqr = 3 * 3; */
```

Don't be confused my macros, macros have weird syntax because they are fed into a preprocessor first not directly to the actual true compiler. Macros can have any syntax. Proper C functions have a definite syntax. Use the definite syntax, don't forget it.